# Extremely basic PHP if statement is defying all logic

Tags: php, if-statement, math

I feel embarrassed to post such a simple question but it's Friday the 13th and I don't know if that's having some type of supernatural effect on my code!

Here is my if statement;

```
if ($invoice_grand_total > floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) {
```

The following code;

```
echo $invoice_grand_total . ' = ' . floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])
```

returns;

```
6.88 = 6.88
```

The var_dump;

```
echo $outstanding_invoices_count . ' invoice_grand_total = ' . var_dump($invoice_grand_total) . '<br/>';
echo $outstanding_invoices_count . ' TotalPayments = ' . var_dump(floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) . '<br/>';
```

returns;

```
float(18) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(18) 0 TotalPayments =
float(199) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(199) 0 TotalPayments =
float(125) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(125) 0 TotalPayments =
float(60) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(60) 0 TotalPayments =
float(55) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(55) 0 TotalPayments =
float(60) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(60) 0 TotalPayments =
float(10) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(10) 0 TotalPayments =
float(3.64) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(3.64) 0 TotalPayments =
float(295) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(295) 0 TotalPayments =
float(25.45) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(25.45) 0 TotalPayments =
float(110) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(110) 0 TotalPayments =
float(2.41) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(2.41) 0 TotalPayments =
float(0.04) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(0.04) 0 TotalPayments =
float(25.45) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(25.45) 0 TotalPayments =
float(6.01) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(6.01) 0 TotalPayments =
float(29.09) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(29.09) 0 TotalPayments =
float(6.88) 0 invoice_grand_total =
float(6.88) 0 TotalPayments =
```

Without using var_dump returns;

```
0 invoice_grand_total = 18
0 TotalPayments = 18
0 invoice_grand_total = 199
0 TotalPayments = 199
0 invoice_grand_total = 125
0 TotalPayments = 125
0 invoice_grand_total = 60
0 TotalPayments = 60
0 invoice_grand_total = 55
0 TotalPayments = 55
0 invoice_grand_total = 60
0 TotalPayments = 60
0 invoice_grand_total = 10
0 TotalPayments = 10
0 invoice_grand_total = 3.64
0 TotalPayments = 3.64
0 invoice_grand_total = 295
0 TotalPayments = 295
0 invoice_grand_total = 25.45
0 TotalPayments = 25.45
0 invoice_grand_total = 110
0 TotalPayments = 110
0 invoice_grand_total = 2.41
0 TotalPayments = 2.41
0 invoice_grand_total = 0.04
0 TotalPayments = 0.04
0 invoice_grand_total = 25.45
0 TotalPayments = 25.45
0 invoice_grand_total = 6.01
0 TotalPayments = 6.01
0 invoice_grand_total = 29.09
0 TotalPayments = 29.09
0 invoice_grand_total = 6.88
0 TotalPayments = 6.88
```

Here is the full code block should it help;

```
// outstanding invoice details

echo '<fieldset>
<legend>Outstanding Invoice Details</legend>';

echo '<table class="solid" style="margin:5px;">';

echo '<tr>
    <th>Invoice #</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Invoice Total</th>
    <th>Amount Paid</th>
    <th>Amount Due</th>
  </tr>';

$invoice_grand_total = 0.00;
$outstanding_invoices_count = 0;

$invoice_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts_invoice WHERE invoice_customer_type='" . $invoice_customer_type . "' AND invoice_customer='" . $invoice_customer . "' AND invoice_posted='1' AND invoice_tenancy_id='" . $tenancy_id . "'") or die(mysql_error());

while($invoice_details_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $invoice_details_query )) {

$invoice_grand_total = $invoice_details_row['invoice_total_amount_exc_vat'] + $invoice_details_row['invoice_total_vat_amount'];

$payment_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(invoice_payment_amount) AS TotalPayments FROM accounts_invoice_payment WHERE invoice_payment_invoice_id='" . $invoice_details_row['invoice_id'] . "'") or die(mysql_error());

$payment_details = mysqli_fetch_array( $payment_details_query );

echo $outstanding_invoices_count . ' invoice_grand_total = ' . var_dump($invoice_grand_total) . '<br/>';
echo $outstanding_invoices_count . ' TotalPayments = ' . var_dump(floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) . '<br/>';

if (floatval($invoice_grand_total) > floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) {

$outstanding_invoices_count++;

echo '<tr>
    <td>' . $invoice_grand_total . ' = ' . floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments']) . '</td>
    <td><a href="view_invoice.php?invoice_id=' . $invoice_details_row['invoice_id'] . '" target="_blank">' . $invoice_details_row['invoice_id'] . '</a></td>
    <td>' . ConvertDate($invoice_details_row['invoice_date']) . '</td>
    <td>&pound;' . number_format($invoice_grand_total, 2, '.', ',') . '</td>
    <td>&pound;' . number_format($payment_details['TotalPayments'], 2, '.', ',') . '</td>
    <td>&pound;' . number_format(($invoice_grand_total - $payment_details['TotalPayments']), 2, '.', ',') . '</td>
  </tr>';

}
}

if ($outstanding_invoices_count==0) { echo '<tr><td colspan="10">There are no outstanding invoices.</td></tr>'; }

echo '</table>';

if ($outstanding_invoices_count!=0) {

echo '<table class="nobord">';

echo '<tr><td><span class="red">The above invoices are outstanding for this landlord. Click <a href="add_invoice_payment.php?invoice_customer_type=1&invoice_customer=' . $invoice_customer . '&invoice_tenancy_id=' . $tenancy_id . '">here</a> to add an invoice payment.</span></td></tr>';

echo '</table>';

}

echo '</fieldset>';
```

Why does the if block of `6.88 > 6.88` run despite the condition `6.88 = 6.88`?

**SOLUTION;**

I changed my if statement to;

```
if (round($invoice_grand_total, 2) > round($payment_details['TotalPayments'], 2)) {
```

Comment: could you please add some var_dumps? what datatype are $invoice_grand_total and $payment_details['TotalPayments']?

Comment: Have you used var_dump? Ever considered floating point precision? Compare the `bin2hex(pack("d"))` if you aren't sure.

Comment: if (floatval($invoice_grand_total) > floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) {

Comment: Added the var_dumps which are identical

Comment: @coder - Just tried that change, didn't make any difference

Comment: @MichaelLB Could you add the var_dump right before the if statement and share the results? (Unless if its already done like that)

Comment: @Tony - The results are different having moved the var_dump, see edited post!

Comment: @MichaelLB I don't understand the "Returns". Could you seperate the result for each variable?

Comment: @MichaelLB Could you add an incremental variable and echo it?

Comment: if (number_format(floatval($invoice_grand_total),2) > number_format(floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments']),2)) {

Comment: @Tony What do you mean by 'Could you add an incremental variable and echo it?'

Comment: @MichaelLB replace the echoes with this echo $outstanding_invoices_count . '. invoice_grand_total = ' . var_dump($invoice_grand_total) . '<br/>;
echo $outstanding_invoices_count . '. TotalPayments = ' . var_dump(floatval($payment_details['TotalPayments'])) . '<br/>;

Comment: @Tony I understand, just made the changes

Comment: @MichaelLB I don't understand why results start with "float(18)" .. it should start with "0 invoice_grand_total = "

Comment: I think the var_dump alters the formatting slightly

Comment: could you please replace it with simple echo - not var_dump

Comment: @Tony See latest edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133070/discussion-between-tony-and-michael-lb).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you never compare floating-point values for equality like this, you need to use a smallest acceptable difference:

[Do not compare floating point numbers for equality.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but does it matter that much when only working to two decimal places? Also, it would be interesting to find out why my current code doesn't work as it appears to defy logic

Comment: Floating point numbers are NOT 100% accurate! Your calculation in PHP may return 10.00000000001 which is NOT equal to 10.

Comment: Use sprintf ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php ) to format the floats before you compare them.

Comment: Whilst this answer didn't help me entirely, it certainly pointed me in the right direction